# How to generate SSH v2 key for ubuntu one

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core

I want to generate a ssh v2 key for my ubuntu one account to be able to log onto ubuntu core on my raspberry key. I follow the instructions outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) but every time I want to import the key on Ubuntu One it states 
"Invalid SSH key data: 'ssh-rsa -..."
I did the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And copied the contents of file `id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The key needs to be 4096 bits so the command is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```